# GooglePlus framwork(objc-c) files in a Swift framework

Tags: objective-c, swift, frameworks, google-plus, target

I want to include GooglePlus framework in my swift framework, but since i'm not able to include a bridging header, I am bit clueless on how to include this framework in my framework target

Answer (score 0):

It seems that module.map is the only solution i found so far that works.

```
module GooglePlus [system] {
    header "src/Google/headers/GooglePlus.h"
    export *
}

module GoogleOpenSource [system] {
    header "src/Google/headers/GoogleOpenSource.h"
    export *
}
```